# What does this picture rebus represent?

Tags: wordplay, visual, rebus

#### What does this picture rebus represent?

[image: Curious picture rebus]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd say it is

> Forewarned (four warning signs) is forearmed (four armed)

Comment: Yup! It's gotta be.

Comment: I like the logic of this, but there isn't a wordplay tag..

Comment: @Xylius, there is now!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil point taken nicely

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

> "Safety is of the lord" from [Proverbs 21:31](http://biblehub.com/kjv/proverbs/21.htm).